# How to make sure CONSTANTS will always be set

Tags: php, include, constants

I am developing a web app and I need to make sure that the constants will always be set, and I am not sure if using a config.php file and including it in the index.php will work...

What happens if the user does not touch the index.php file? what if it goes directly to (for example) www.theapp.com/anotherpage.php

How can I make sure that the constants will be available even if the user goes directly to another page that does not have included the config.php?

Do I have to include it in every page I make?

Comment: Yes, a central config file. And yes, you need to include it in every invocatable script.

Comment: Yes, you do. Each page serves as an entrypoint to your webapplication, so your global constants will have to be loaded on each request.

Comment: Thank you. So... creating a config.php file and using DEFINE is the best way I guess... I think I've seen it in action in Wordpress. Or is there something else you can suggest to make it elegant but simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, You can use a PHP `auto_prepend_file` script in your PHP ini to do this as it will be run before any of your user-land scripts:

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the
>   main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require
>   function, so include_path is used.

So you can add an ini line like:

```
auto_prepend_file="/home/user/script.php"
```

The in /home/user/script.php:

```
define('CONSTANT_NAME', 'your nice value here');
```

Now in your PHP scripts you can access CONSTANT_NAME from wherever you like as it is available in all PHP scripts.

Comment: In case I am working with WAMP and Localhost as the server address. The file string would be "localhost/config.php". Right? how to make it relative so it works on the internet and local development servers?